# Angular2 реактивные формы. FormArray. передать FormGroup в кастомный компонент

Tags: веб-программирование, angular2

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли возможность передавать FormGroup в кастомный компонент. 
Например имеется форма:

```
personForm = new FromGroup({
  name: new FormControl(''),
  family: new FormControl(0),
  address: new FormArray([]),
})
```

а поле адрес будет тоже группой полей например:

```
addressItemForm = new FromGroup({
   street: new FormControl(''),
   id: new FormControl(0),
   codeCladr: new FormControl(0),
})
```

и я хочу иметь свой компонент например AddressComponent который будет работать с addressItemForm...
Из рассматриваемых примеров все приводят только "плоскую форму" без всех возможных вложенностей..

Comment: Привет =) Что в итоге Вы хотите получить?

Comment: Привет! 
я хочу элемент массива реактивной формы вынести в отдельный компонент что бы его затем в других страницах использовать

Comment: То есть Вы хотите иметь компонент(**к примеру форму поиска по сайту**), который можно будет внедрять в нужный компонент?

Comment: Да, а почему бы нет? разработать так сказать базовый набор компонентов и модулей которые в дальнейшем можно набрасывать на страницу с меньшими затратами времени..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за ответы! Особенно @Denisoed за предложенные статьи. Почитал осмыслил и все получилось! Решение которое завелось:

Родительский компонент имеет вид: 
**person.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'person',
  templateUrl: './person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person.component.scss']
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

    personForm: FromGroup;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  initF():FormGroup{
    return new FromGroup({
        name: new FromControl(),
        ...
        address: new FormArray([]),
        ...

    })
  }
}
```

**person.component.html** имеет вид:

```
<form [formGroup]>
...
<div *ngFor="let address of personForm.controls['address'].controls;let i=index;" 
     formGroupName={{i}}>
  <address [formControl]="address">
  </address>
</div>
...
</form>
```

и компонент адреса имеет вид **address.component.ts**:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.scss']
})
export class AddressComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  private onChangeCallback: Function;
  private onTouchedCallback: Function;


  addressForm: FromGroup;


  constructor() {
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    debugger;
    if (obj) {
    } else {
      this.addressForm = this.initForm();
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }


  initForm(): FormGroup {
    return new FromGroup({
      name: new FromControl(),
      address: new FormArray([]),
    })
  }
}
```

Спасибо всем больше за помощь!

PS: в примере продемонстрирована идея, и если немного подредактировать то код вполне рабочий

Comment: Это победа друг мой =)

Comment: @Denisoed а что тогда?

Answer (score 0):

Давайте возьмем для примера так же форму поиска по сайту
**Создаем компонент:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  formSearch: FormGroup;   

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,) { 
      this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.formSearch = this formBuilder.group([
       inputSearch: ['', Validators.required ]
    ]);
  }

  onSearch(searchText) {
     // Отправляете текст сервису, который должен отправить запрос на сервер...
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Создаем саму форму в файле **search.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formSearch">
   <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..." formControlName="inputSearch" #searchText>
   <button (click)="onSearch(searchText.value)">Search</button>
</form>
```

После спокойно вставляете тег **app-search** в нужный вам компонент, а конкретнее в HTML документ =)

Comment: наверное я не правильно выразился.

Comment: например у нас есть реактивная форма с полем FormArray

Comment: Проблема в том что Ваш вопрос не до конца понятен, поэтому ни кто не может дать ответ =) Перепишите Ваш вопрос более понятно

Comment: в поле FormArray используется FormGroup 
например так 
myF = new FromGroup({
...
myFormArray: new FormArray(),
...
});

и есть элемент формы например 
formArrayItem = new FormGroup({
id: new FromControl(),
code:  new FromControl(),
addressString: new FromControl(),
house: new FromControl(),
...
})

и есть мой (кастомный) компонент адреса например 

@Component({selector: 'my-addres', templeteURL: '....', })
export class MyAddres implement ControlValueAccessor {
....
....

}

и я хочу передать элемент FormArray в свой компонент адреса...

Comment: наверное я хочу что то страшное... или по китайски выражаюсь(

Comment: Я тоже такой же))) Мне из за этого сайт запретил задавать вопросы))))

Comment: как я вижу в темплейте это
<div *ngFor="let addres of personForm.controls['addres'].cotrols;let i=index;"> 
<my-address formGroup={{i}}></my-address>
</div>

и как я понимаю в моем компаненте должен сработать метод writeValue(obj: any) от интерфейса  ControlValueAccessor но такого не происходит... 
вот я и ломаю голову почему и как такое можно сделать...

Comment: @aknysh Я подумаю, поищу, чуть позже отпишусь =)

Comment: большое спасибо!) может еще кто подключится)

Comment: @aknysh Может эта статья поможет https://medium.com/@maks.zhitlov/reactive-forms-in-angular-2f8abe884f79. честно сказать я тоже новичок в Ангуляре, много не знаю еще =)

Comment: спасибо за статью, посмотрел статью но там тоже используют так сказать "плоскую" форму для примера и нет передачи FormGroup в свои компоненты... оставил комментарий может быть кто то  что то посоветует...
тут даже и проблема загуглить... по запросам реактивной формы вываливаются ответы по тому что такое реактивная форма((

Comment: @aknysh https://habrahabr.ru/company/tinkoff/blog/323270/